# How to add attribute to custom angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I need to add an attribute to a custom angular directive but I do not know how to bind the attribute (width) from the html part to the javascript that manages the behavior.

this is the html:

```
<div class="dropdown btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="dropdown-label">{{initialValue}}</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-scrollable" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="value in values"
            ng-click="clickHandler(value,$event)">
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">{{value}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

this is the javascript behind html:

```
angular.module('platform.directives').directive('dropdownComponent', function() {
    'use strict';
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        initialValue: '@',
        values: '=',
        selectedValue: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'modules/directives/dropdown/dropdown.html',
    link: function(scope) {
        scope.clickHandler = function findAndFillSelectedValueAndCloseDropDownArea(value, event) {
            var $target = $(event.currentTarget);
            $target.closest('.btn-group')
                    .find('[data-bind="dropdown-label"]').text($target.text())
                    .end()
                    .children('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
            scope.selectedValue = value;
            return false;
        };
    }
};
});
```

this is a usage:

```
<dropdownComponent 
   initial-value={{'PERMISSION.CREATE.DROPDOWN.RESOURCE'|translate}}
   selected-value="permissionCtrl.permission.resourceId"
   values="permissionCtrl.resources" 
   width="200px">
</dropdownComponent>
```

So basically I want to add a width attribute to this angular directive.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass it to the scope like you do with all 3 other variables:

```
scope: {
        initialValue: '@',
        values: '=',
        selectedValue: '=',
        width: "@"
    },
```

And now you can just use `scope.width` in the javascript of the directive to add to elements for example.

And in HTML (which you should change `dropdownComponent` to `dropdown-component` by the way):

```
<dropdown-component 
        initial-value={{'PERMISSION.CREATE.DROPDOWN.RESOURCE'|translate}} 
        selected-value="permissionCtrl.permission.resourceId" 
        values="permissionCtrl.resources" 
        width="200px"></dropdown-component>
```

**EDIT:** In your directive HTML, change the first button to:

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-default" 
        data-bind="dropdown-label" 
        ng-style="width: {{width}}">{{initialValue}}</button>
```

Comment: as you can see in the directive's hml, this dropdown is composed out of 2 buttons, I need the width that i set in the custome directive to actually set the first button width...

Comment: ng-click="clickHandler(value,$event)" this needs to contain the with param

Comment: @aurelius Then do `ng-click="clickHandler(value,$event, {{width}})"`